# More space between legends and end of chart

Tags: android, kotlin, highcharts

How do i make more space between the legends and the pie chart without modifying the chart's size

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you can use `legend.margin`, `legend.padding` or `legend.y` options. If you are afraid of affecting the pie size, you can set it as a constant value by `pie.chart` option.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rfaq2dm6/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.margin
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.size